# how to write regular expression to validate a string using regex in C#

Tags: c#

I need to validate a user input based on condition. i wrote a regular expression to do so, but it's failing not sure why.
Can somebody point where i am making mistake?

```
Regex AccuracyCodeHexRegex = new Regex(@"^[PTQA]((0|8)[01234567]){2}$");
```

This is what i am trying to validate(If the string is a subset of these strings then it is valid):

> Phh, Thh, Qhh, Ahh where 'h' is a hex digit in the set {00, 80, 01, 81, 02, 82, 03, 83, 04, 84, 05, 85, 06, 86, 07, 87}

Ex: P00 is valid
P20 is not valid

Comment: Validate **how**? What makes a valid versus an invalid string? It is not clear from your question if the string you posted is valid or not. Can you post several _examples_ of valid and invalid strings and explain the validation rules?

Comment: I have given the check in the question.Phh, Thh, Qhh, Ahh where 'h' is a hex digit in the set {00, 80, 01, 81, 02, 82, 03, 83, 04, 84, 05, 85, 06, 86, 07, 87} means valid

Comment: One example is not enough. What makes that valid? What is an _invalid_ string?

Comment: I read your title as "How to write a regular expresion using RegEx." Lolwut?

Comment: @Charu: do you mean `P82` is a valid string, and `P93` is not, for example?

Comment: P8001 is valid, T0282 is Valid X8001 is not ....

Comment: @Mr47 right, that's correct.

Comment: How is it failing? Does it match when it shouldn't, fail to match when it should, hang, throw an exception? It looks OK to me.

Comment: From the regex, `Q0782` is valid.

Comment: The Regex is fine, i think the way you are applying it may be wrong. More code please :)

Comment: @Oded how do you figure? There's not a `9` in there anywhere.

Comment: I passed P00, but still no match.

Comment: So if its correct, P00 etc should be matched right?

Comment: _`P00` doesn't match what you describe_. You say `Phh` where _each_ `h` is two digits (from a set), but `P00` is `Ph` where `h` is two digits.

Comment: @Charu - Why is `P00` valid? It shouldn't be (if `h` is `00` and you have _two_ `hh` - `P0000` should be valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Regex `^[PTQA](?:(?:0|8)[01234567]){2}$`

Applies to the following :

```
P8001
P8002
P0281
P8005
```

and so on, because you are repeating the number matches by `{2}`

To validate something like P81 / P05, you need to change that to `{1}`

Comment: you don't nedd `{1}`you can simplue use `^[PTQA](?:(?:0|8)[0-7])$`

Answer (score 2):

I would write :

```
^[PTQA]((0|8)[0-7])$
```

you don't seem to need the `{2}` which validates strings like `P0707`

Comment: can be simplified to `^[PTQA](?:(?:0|8)[0-7])$`

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify your regex to `^[PTQA](?:(?:0|8)[0-7])$` which will do the trick for you

if you need speed regex aren't terribly fast and usually simple lookups on static values can be implemented with a switch-case. They aren't that nice when it comes to maintainability but if the values are fairly stable and only used in this one place that shouldn't be too much of a concern. If it is you can use a HashSet of all the valid values.

Using a HashSet:

```
var leading = new[]{'P','T','Q','A'};
var firstDigit = new []{'0','8'};
var lastDigit = new []{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7'};

var set = new HashSet<string>(from l in leading
                              from f in firstDigit
                              from lst in lastDigit
                              select l + f + lst);

public bool IsOk(string value){
   return set.Contains(value);
}
```

or using switch-case:

```
public bool IsOk(string value){
   if(value.length != 3) return false;
   switch(value[0]){
       case 'P':
       case 'T':
       case 'Q':
       case 'A':
          switch(value[1]){
               case '0':
               case '8':
                   switch(value[2]){
                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                            return true;
                   }
         }

   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the possible hex digits in a list you could build the regex automatically like so

```
var hexs = new List {"00", "80", "01", "81", "02"};
var regex = string.Format("^[PTQA]({0})", string.Join("|", hexs));
var accuracyCodeHexRegex = new Regex(regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the possible values are known, why don't you compare to an array of this known possibles values?

```
void Foo(){

    var valueToTest1 = "P07";
    var valueToText2 = "Z54";

    TestValue(valueToTest1);
    TestValue(valueToTest1);
}

bool TestValue(string stringToTest)
{
    var hexValues = new string[] { "00", "80", "01", "81", "02", "82", "03", "83", "04", "84", "05", "85", "06", "86", "07", "87"};
    var leftValues = new char[] { 'P', 'Q', 'H' };

    var left = stringToTest[0];
    var right = strintToTest.SubString(1,2);

    return leftValues.Contains(left) && hexValues.Contains(right);
}
```

This is a lot simpler than using a regex and I believe far more performant

Comment: I have to use Regex, we have other comparisons also. Need to stick to regex.

Comment: Indeed, I doubt if regex is required and more than likely would be the least efficient solution

Comment: @Charu: what kind of other comparison may be related to this test?

Comment: if you are going to hardcode the values a switch is going to be even faster than searching in an array